Pottery clay for aquarium
I just discovered nearby a pottery club, and I was thinking to create myself a few ornaments myself. Actually, I kind of have in mind hiding spots for the bottom dwellers.
So the question is: it pottery clay safe for aquarium? I plan to not have it "painted" with anything - except that the clay should be black in the entire volume.
Note: they have the special ovens and they can cook it for me.

After a full firing, it should be fine, just as you can use that pottery to hold human food and drink.

Agree if it’s safe for humans, probably ok in a fish tank. But if it’s unglazed, it’s likely to get covered in algae if your tank has any.
